# Unipotent matrix with all block matrices having non-zero determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, group-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, unipotent-matrices

Let $M\in \mathrm{SL}(4, \mathbb{Z})$ with all eigenvalues equal to $1$ (i.e. $M$ is a unipotent matrix).

Write $M=\begin{bmatrix}
A_1&A_2\\
A_3&A_4 
\end{bmatrix}, 
$ where each $A_i$ is a $2$ by $2$ sumbatrix of $M$.

Let $a_i = \mathrm{det}(A_i)$.

Consider the matrix $A =  \begin{bmatrix}
a_1&a_2\\
a_3&a_4 
\end{bmatrix}$,

**Question**: Is it possible that

1. All $a_i$'s are non-zero?
2. The matrix $A$ is in $\mathrm{GL}(2, \mathbb{Z})$, and has one eigenvalue with an absolute value not equal to $1$?

Question 1 has been answered by  Dietrich Burde, any hint with question 2 would be really appreciated.

Comment: ah, the fact that all elements have to be integers makes this a lot harder.

Comment: For context see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4477214/an-example-of-a-matrix-in-mathrmsl4-mathbbz-with-the-following-proper/4477266#4477266). @BenjaminWang Actually, we still have many integral solutions, so it is not too difficult. We only need to find *some* solutions.

Comment: And indeed, there are many integral matrices of this type. I suppose, the next question about this you can answer yourself without posting it.

Comment: Thank you @DietrichBurde, my final question is to find $M$ such that $A$ is in $\mathrm{GL}(2, \mathbb{Z})$, and has one eigenvalue with an absolute value not equal to $1$. I haven't been able to come up with an example for a while. If I can't find one at the end, would it be okay for me to post it?

Comment: But the matrix $A$ in my answer has characteristic polynomial $t^2-6t+1$, so $\det(A)=1$ and the eigenvalues are $3\pm 2\sqrt{2}$. Really, try it yourself next time. You can do it.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thank you for providing so many examples, I will make sure to test all the examples I know before I post another question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the ideas from the previous [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4477214/an-example-of-a-matrix-in-mathrmsl4-mathbbz-with-the-following-proper/4477266#4477266) we immediately find examples, e.g.,
$$
M=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 4 & 1 & 0 \cr 
36 & 0 & 49 & 1 \cr 2 & -3 & 2 & 0 \cr 1 & -1 & 0 & 2 \end{pmatrix}. 
$$
Here $M$ has characteristic polynomial $(t-1)^4$.
The matrix of determinants is given by
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix} -144 & 1 \cr 1 & 4 \end{pmatrix}.
$$
For the second question, take
$$
M=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \cr 
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \cr 1 & 0 & 0 & 2 \cr 0 & 1 & -3 & 4 \end{pmatrix}. 
$$
Then the matrix $A$ of block determinants is given by
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 \cr 1 & 6 \end{pmatrix}\in SL_2(\Bbb Z).
$$
The eigenvalues do not have absolute value $1$.