# Matrix that is conjugate to its own inverse in $GL(4,\mathbb{Z})$

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, sagemath

I am looking for examples of matrices that are conjugate to their own inverses in $GL(4,\mathbb{Z})$, i.e. $A=B^{-1}A^{-1}B$ for $A,B\in GL(4,\mathbb{Z}),\ A\neq I,\ B\neq I$.

I couldn't find it either by myself or Sage (it runs for a very long time and never gives an output).

I wonder if there are such matrices. If they exist, how can I find an example? I kind of want to see how they look like and be able to find a lot of examples...

Thanks in advance!

Edit: Also, I hope it is not in $GL(2,\mathbb{Z})\times GL(2,\mathbb{Z})$ or $GL(3,\mathbb{Z})$.

Edit 2: I apologize... I further hope the matrices are not finite order (better all the eigenvalues are not on the unit circle, i.e., hyperbolic matrices).

Comment: Small note: if you want the inverse to also have integer coefficients, you must require that the determinant of your matrix is $\pm 1$.

Comment: I think you should stop changing the question and accept the answer!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$$A=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}0&0&0&1\\ 1&0&0&0\\ 0&1&0&0\\ 0&0&1&0\end{array}\right).$$
Finding a matching $B$ is left as an exercise to the reader with the hint: the permutation $(1234)$ and its inverse $(4321)$ are conjugates in $S_4$.

That matrix does have $\lambda=1$ as an eigenvalue, so it is conjugate to a matrix in $GL_1\times GL_3$. Because $\lambda=-1$ is also an eigenvalue, it also stabilizes two 2-dimensional subspaces over $\Bbb{Q}$ and is thus also conjugate to a matrix from $GL_2\times GL_2$. Apparently this is undesirable.

---

**Matching the updated version of the question:**

The palindromic polynomial
$$f(x)=x^4+x^3+3x^2+x+1$$
is irreducible over $\Bbb{Z}$ because it remains irreducible after reduction modulo two. Because it is palindromic, $x^4 f(1/x)=f(x)$, its zeros have the property that $f(\rho)=0$ if and only if $f(1/\rho)=0$. Its [companion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix) is
$$
A=\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & -3 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & -1 \\
\end{array}
\right),
$$
when the inverse is
$$
A^{-1}=\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 -3 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 -1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right).$$

The palindromic property of $f(x)$ then tells us that $A$ and $A^{-1}$ share the same set of simple eigenvalues. This is because the eigenvalues of a companion matrix $A$ are the roots of the polynomial $f(x)$. Furthermore, the eigenvalues of $A^{-1}$ are the reciprocals of the eigenvalues of $A$, which in this case are still zeros of $f(x)$, and thus the eigenvalues of $A$.

The shared simple eigenvalues already mean that the two matrices are automatically conjugate in $GL_4(\Bbb{C})$, but it turns out that they are also conjugate in $GL_4(\Bbb{Z})$.
Unless I made a mistake we can use the same $B$ as above, namely
$$B=\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right).
$$

Irreducibility of $f(x)$ translates into the non-existence of a non-trivial subspace $V\subset \Bbb{Q}^4$ such that $AV=V$. This rules out the possibility of $A$ being conjugate to a matrix from $GL_1(\Bbb{Q})\times GL_3(\Bbb{Q})$ or $GL_2(\Bbb{Q})\times GL_2(\Bbb{Q})$.

---

The same procedure works for any palindromic quartic. So it is also possible to arrange all the eigenvalues to be real. This happens for example with the companion matrix of
$$g(x)=x^4 - 5 x^3 - 13 x^2 - 5 x + 1.$$

Comment: "Left as an exercise," lmao what!?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But I take this as a matrix in $GL(3,\mathbb{Z})$ because it factors as blocks? I edited once more on the question...

Comment: @chikurin Then the first idea that comes to me would be to consider the companion matrix of a polynomial like $(x^2-4x+1)(x^2-6x+1)$ with eigenvalues $2\pm\sqrt3$ and  $3\pm 2\sqrt2$ that pair up nicely (are each others inverses). Or would you consider that to come from $GL_2\times GL_2$?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I guess this might be fine? As long as in the integer form it is not in blocks... I'll think more...

Comment: @chikurin The companion matrix of an irreducible palindromic seems to work.

Comment: Thanks! Let me try to understand this with my very rusty algebra...

Answer (score 2):

Using Gröbner bases, it is very easy to just come up with several types of matrices
$A\in GL_4(\Bbb Z)$, where not all eigenvalues lie on the unit circle. For example, take
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \cr 
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \cr 1 & 0 & 0 & 2 \cr 1 & -1 & 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}. 
$$
Now the condition $A=B^{-1}A^{-1}B$ can be rewritten as
$ABA=B$, which is just a system of linear equations in the entries of $B$ together with the polynomial condition that $\det(B)=\pm 1$.
In our case, we can easily find some $B\in GL_4(\Bbb Z)$ with this condition, for example
$$
B=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 2 \cr 
1 & -1 & 0 & 1 \cr 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \cr 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}. 
$$
The advantage is, that you can vary the matrices as you want.
First you vary $A$, which can be computed. Only afterwards you compute $B$. If you do it together, the equations are too hard. This way you may be able, perhaps, to find matrices of infinite order. Note, however, that the second part may have no solution for certain $A$.

Reference for the computations:

[An example of a matrix in $\mathrm{SL}(4, \mathbb{Z})$ with the following properties](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4477214/an-example-of-a-matrix-in-mathrmsl4-mathbbz-with-the-following-proper/4477266#4477266)

Comment: Thanks for the answer (and the reference)!

Answer (score 1):

In any group, if $u$, $v$ are of order $2$ then

$$u(uv)u= vu = (uv)^{-1}$$

so $uv$ is conjugate to $(uv)^{-1}$.

Now, to produce elements of order $2$, start with some standard ones (like diagonal matrices) and conjugate them by other elements.